# Reshape data frame with different column lengths into two columns replicating column ID

Tags: r, multiple-columns, reshape

I have the following data frame, with different row lengths:

```
myvar <- as.data.frame(rbind(c("Walter","NA","NA","NA","NA"),
                             c("Walter","NA","NA","NA","NA"),
                             c("Walter","Jesse","NA","NA","NA"),
                             c("Gus","Tuco","Mike","NA","NA"), 
                             c("Gus","Mike","Hank","Saul","Flynn")))
ID <- as.factor(c(1:5))   
data.frame(ID,myvar)

ID     V1    V2   V3   V4    V5
 1 Walter    NA   NA   NA    NA
 2 Walter    NA   NA   NA    NA
 3 Walter Jesse   NA   NA    NA
 4    Gus  Tuco Mike   NA    NA
 5    Gus  Mike Hank Saul Flynn
```

My goal is to switch this data frame into a two column data frame. The first column would be the ID and the other one would be the character name. Note that the ID must be correspondent to the row the character were originally placed. I'm expecting the following result:

```
ID      V
1  Walter    
2  Walter
3  Walter
3  Jesse
4  Gus
4  Tuco
4  Mike
5  Gus
5  Mike
5  Hank
5  Saul
5  Flynn
```

I've tried dcast {reshape2} but it doesn't returned what I need. It is noteworthy that my original data frame is quite big. Any tips? Cheers.

Comment: and `dcast` is the opposite of what you want, that's for going from long to wide

Comment: Do NOT use data.frame(cbind(,,,)) or data.frame(rbind). Bad things will happen.

Comment: Sorry about the NA as character. My bad. But thank you all for the answers!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `unlist`

```
 res <- subset(data.frame(ID,value=unlist(myvar[-1], 
                              use.names=FALSE)), value!='NA')
 res
 #   ID  value
 #1   1 Walter
 #2   2 Walter
 #3   3 Walter
 #4   4    Gus
 #5   5    Gus
 #6   3  Jesse
 #7   4   Tuco
 #8   5   Mike
 #9   4   Mike
 #10  5   Hank
 #11  5   Saul
 #12  5  Flynn
```

**NOTE:** The `NAs` are 'character' elements in the dataset, it is better to create it without quotes so that it will be real NAs and we can remove it by `na.omit`, `is.na`, `complete.cases` etc.

#### data

```
myvar <- data.frame(ID,myvar)
```

Answer (score 7):

```
myvar <- as.data.frame(rbind(c("Walter","NA","NA","NA","NA"),
                             c("Walter","NA","NA","NA","NA"),
                             c("Walter","Jesse","NA","NA","NA"),
                             c("Gus","Tuco","Mike","NA","NA"), 
                             c("Gus","Mike","Hank","Saul","Flynn")))
ID <- as.factor(c(1:5))   
df <- data.frame(ID, myvar)
```

Using base reshape. (I'm converting your `"NA"` character strings to `NA` which you may not have to do, this is just due to how you created this example)

```
df[df == 'NA'] <- NA
na.omit(reshape(df, direction = 'long', varying = list(2:6))[, c('ID','V1')])

#     ID     V1
# 1.1  1 Walter
# 2.1  2 Walter
# 3.1  3 Walter
# 4.1  4    Gus
# 5.1  5    Gus
# 3.2  3  Jesse
# 4.2  4   Tuco
# 5.2  5   Mike
# 4.3  4   Mike
# 5.3  5   Hank
# 5.4  5   Saul
# 5.5  5  Flynn
```

or using `reshape2`

```
library('reshape2')
## na.omit(melt(df, id.vars = 'ID')[, c('ID','value')])

## or better yet as ananda suggests:
melt(df, id.vars = 'ID', na.rm = TRUE)[, c('ID','value')]

#    ID  value
# 1   1 Walter
# 2   2 Walter
# 3   3 Walter
# 4   4    Gus
# 5   5    Gus
# 8   3  Jesse
# 9   4   Tuco
# 10  5   Mike
# 14  4   Mike
# 15  5   Hank
# 20  5   Saul
# 25  5  Flynn
```

you get warnings that the factor levels over the columns are not the same but that's fine.

Comment: I would have changed the arguments to include `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`

Comment: `melt` has an `na.rm` argument, so you should not need to use `na.omit`. However, because of how the data were created, you need to make them into real `NA` (which you did).

Answer (score 6):

Fix your `"NA"` so that they are actually `NA` first:

```
mydf[mydf == "NA"] <- NA
```

Using some subsetting to do it all in one fell swoop:

```
data.frame(ID=mydf$ID[row(mydf[-1])[!is.na(mydf[-1])]], V=mydf[-1][!is.na(mydf[-1])])

#   ID      V
#1   1 Walter
#2   2 Walter
#3   3 Walter
#4   4    Gus
#5   5    Gus
#6   3  Jesse
#7   4   Tuco
#8   5   Mike
#9   4   Mike
#10  5   Hank
#11  5   Saul
#12  5  Flynn
```

Or much more readable in base R:

```
sel <- which(!is.na(mydf[-1]), arr.ind=TRUE)
data.frame(ID=mydf$ID[sel[,1]], V=mydf[-1][sel])
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `tidyr`

```
library("tidyr")

myvar <- as.data.frame(rbind(c("Walter","NA","NA","NA","NA"),
                             c("Walter","NA","NA","NA","NA"),
                             c("Walter","Jesse","NA","NA","NA"),
                             c("Gus","Tuco","Mike","NA","NA"), 
                             c("Gus","Mike","Hank","Saul","Flynn")))
ID <- as.factor(c(1:5))   

myvar <- data.frame(ID,myvar)

myvar %>% 
    gather(ID, Name, V1:V5 ) %>%
    select(ID, value) %>%
    filter(value != "NA")
```

If your NAs are coded as `NA` instead of `"NA"`, then we can in fact use the `na.rm = TRUE` option in `gather`. E.g.:

```
myvar[myvar == "NA"] <- NA
myvar %>% 
    gather(ID, Name, V1:V5, na.rm = TRUE ) %>%
    select(ID, value)
```

gives

```
   ID  value
1   1 Walter
2   2 Walter
3   3 Walter
4   4    Gus
5   5    Gus
6   3  Jesse
7   4   Tuco
8   5   Mike
9   4   Mike
10  5   Hank
11  5   Saul
12  5  Flynn
```

Comment: The key in this solution and @rawr's solutions is that we remove NA's after concatenating the name columns while keeping the row number.

Comment: I keep getting an error: Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'value' not found

Comment: What is your version of `tidyr`? There is some problem with new assignment of names in some versions of `tidyr`, don't run the last `select` command to see what column names you are left with.

Comment: now deprecated- use pivot_longer instead

Answer (score 0):

Since you are thinking of huge data,

time performance would matter, even sorting afterwards could take forever

Here's my solution. You better be using `data.table` but here I'll use `reshape2`

1. first solution

```
myvar <- as.data.frame(rbind(c("Walter","NA","NA","NA","NA"),
                             c("Walter","NA","NA","NA","NA"),
                             c("Walter","Jesse","NA","NA","NA"),
                             c("Gus","Tuco","Mike","NA","NA"), 
                             c("Gus","Mike","Hank","Saul","Flynn")))
ID <- as.factor(c(1:5))   

dat = data.frame(ID,myvar)
dat[] <- lapply(dat, function(x) {x[x=="NA"]=NA; x})

str(dat$V5)

library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)

dat2 <- melt(dat, id.vars="ID", measure.vars = paste0("V", 1:5), na.rm=TRUE)
dat2
dat2[, c('ID', 'value')]
```

2. second solution needs some preprocessing. for huge data, i would recommend `data.table`

```
datB <- t(dat)
datB
colnames(datB) <- datB["ID", ]
datB <- datB[-1,]

melt(datB, measure.vars = 1:5, na.rm=TRUE)[, c('Var2', 'value')]
```

you do not need sorting afterwards